# Reading data of android phones using Java

Tags: java, android, android-activity

My goal is to build *an application to send text messages through android phones using computer connected to the phone using a cable*.

In order to do so and to provide a good UI, I will need to read messages from my android phone to my computer. I have a slight idea that to do this I will first have to make an application using the message reading privileges and put it on my phone. Then I would need to read the messages through that application.

What I do not know is that how will I read this to my computer which has been connected using a cable to the phone. I will be using Java as the language to do this. Please advise.

Comment: Look at the way firefox and chrome do it.